# Одномерный массив С++

Tags: c++, массивы

Дан массив N[13]. Найти и вывести минимальный элемент и его индекс. Если сумма минимального элемента и его индекса больше 12, то все нулевые элементы заменить на минимальный элемент, иначе все отрицательные умножить на 2. Вывести полученный массив.

Не заменяет на Ноль и на минимальный элемент

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int N = 13;
    int n[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N;i++) {
        cout << "Vvedite elementy N[" << i << "]:";
        cin >> n[i];
    }


    int min = 0;
    int sum = 0, nul = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        if (n[i] < n[min])
        {
            min = i;
            sum = n[min] + min;
        }



    if (sum > 12)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            if (n[i] == 0)
                n[i] = n[min];
    }
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            if (n[i] < 0)
                n[i] *= 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        std::cout << n[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Пока я в этой стадии: сперва хочу вывести Мин.элемент и Индекс этого элемента. Вот пока мой успех, но не понятно, почему сперва выводит другой элемент, хотя он не минимальный, а потом только правильный элемент:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int N = 13;
    int n[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N;i++){
        cout << "Vvedite elementy N[" << i << "]:";
        cin >> n[i];
    }

    int min = 0, sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (n[i] < n[min])
        {
            min = i;
            cout << "index: " << min << "; Min. element: " << n[min] << ";";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А действительно, что не так?

Comment: Вашу проблему нам предлагается угадать самостоятельно?

Comment: @VladD, ну я вижу только повторное объявление `i` и то что сообщения о минимальных элементах выводятся каждый раз как  будет найден элемент меньше, а не один раз после цикла

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, если уж ТС реально хочет знать ответ, он должен быть в качестве вежливого шага рассказать, в чём дело. Ошибка компиляции? Тогда включить точное сообщение и строку, к которой относится. Ошибка в рантайме? Тогда запустить из-под отладчика, дать точную строку с проблемой и точное сообщение отладчика, плюс значения задействованных переменных. Неправильный результат? Дать тестовые данные и ожидаемый вывод, а также реальный вывод. Проблемы со стилем? Сообщить об этом. А так выглядит, как будет бы нас просят проверить лабу и подправить, чтобы препод был доволен.

Comment: @Oma Sydykov Это плохая идея таким кардинальным образом менять вопрос, когда уже дан ответ. Это будет вводить в заблуждение тех, кто будет читать вопрос и ответ. Вы могли бы закрыть этот вопрос и задать еще один новый, сделав те исправления, которые я показал в своем ответе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Старайтесь не смешивать две различные функции в одной функции.

Например, в этом фрагменте кода

```
int min = 0;
cout << "Vse elementy: ";
int i = 0;
while (i < N) {
    cout << n[i] <<" ";
    if (n[i] < min) {
        min = n[i];
        cout <<"Minimalnyi element: "<<min;
        cout << endl;
        cout <<"Index min. elementa: "<<i;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Совершенно не ясно, что вы пытаетесь сделать. То ли вы хотите вывести на консоль все элементы массива, то ли найти минимальный элемент массива.

К тому же сообщение о минимальном элементе следует поместить после цикла. Иначе у вас несколько раз будет выводиться сообщение о различных минимальных элементах.

Сначала выведите элементы массива на консоль в отдельном цикле, а в другом цикле найдите минимальный элемент, если это требуется.

Учтите, что начальное значение минимального элемента равного 0 некорректно. В массиве все элементы могут быть больше нуля, и тогда ваша программа выдаст неправильный результат, что минимальный элемент равен 0, хотя такового в массиве нет.

Вывести массив на консоль вы можете, например, следующим образом:

```
for ( int x : n ) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Или если ваш компилятор не поддерживает циклы for на основе диапазонов, то вы можете написать

```
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << n[i] << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Незачем переменную `i` объявлять вне цикла.

Поиск минимального элемента в массиве может быть сделан следующим образом:

```
int min = 0;

for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ )
{
    if ( n[i] < n[min] ) min = i;
}

std::cout << "Minimalnyi element: "<< n[min] << std::endl;
std::cout << "Index min. elementa: " << min << std::endl;
```

Имейте в виду, что в C++ определен стандартный алгоритм `std::min_element`, объявленный в заголовке `<algorithm>` который находит минимальный элемент в контейнере, включая массивы. Например

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

int *min = std::min_element( n, n + N );

std::cout << "Minimalnyi element: "<< *min << std::endl;
std::cout << "Index min. elementa: " << min - n << std::endl;
```

Также `n` - это не лучшее имя для массива. Обычно имя `n` используется для скаларных целочисленных объектов. Лучше назвать массив именем `a` от слова `array`.

Comment: @OmaSydykov Я вам показал, как найти минимальный элемент и его индекс и вывести их на консоль.

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь!